# Xcode not recognizing custom cell in TableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have identical code in multiple view controllers and can't figure out why the Xcode compiler won't recognize a custom Cell.

In storyboards, the VCs have a view controller containing a tableView with 1 dynamic cell.
This cell is set in identity inspector to a custom cell.

In the file for the VC, in CellForRowAtIndexPath I have the following code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
   
 static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";
     myCustomCell* cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
```

The only difference between the custom cells is some were created in older versions of Xcode and don't have the NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN  and END lines:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface contactCell : UITableViewCell
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *someLabel;

@end

vs.

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

@interface ideaCell : UITableViewCell
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *someLabel;

@end

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```

However, if I set a breakpoint after the working one it shows:

[image]

However, if I set a breakpoint after the non-working on it shows a generic uitableviewcell.

[image]

Why isn't it recognizing the custom Cell?

I have tried deleting the cell and recreating it as well as cleaning the build folder.

Thanks for any suggestion.

Edit:

Here is storyboard:

[image]

[image]

Comment: In the storyboard, do you have an identifier of "Cell" assigned to the cell?

Comment: Yes. Added screenshot above.

Comment: @El Tomato can you explain?

Comment: Sorry, I mean, you are NOT telling the view controller about the table view cell class name.

Comment: Class name should start with capital letter.

Comment: And as El Tomato says, the problem is likely cell registration in the view controller.